# How to check if the difference between 2 dates is > or < 1 month in Jinja2 templates?

Tags: date, ansible, jinja2

I am using jinja2 templates (with Ansible) and in it i require to check the difference between two dates. I do not have the epoch of the dates but i do have them in yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss format (no milliseconds). So my questions:

1) Is there a way in jinja2 to compare two dates ? I do not want to install any library, it has to be a built in feature.

2) If it cannot be done via jinja2, is there a quick logic i can implement to compare them ? Like converting to epoch ? (remember, no milliseconds)

Answer (score 12):

Building on @konstantin-suvorov's answer, you'll want to use the `to_datetime` [filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html).

```
{{ (date1|to_datetime - date2|to_datetime).days }}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is available since Ansible 2.2

Answer (score 3):

Playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - template: src=date.j2 dest=date.txt
      vars:
        date1: 2016-08-04 20:00:12
        date2: 2015-10-06 21:00:12
```

Template:

```
days {{ (date1 - date2).days }}
```

Output:

```
days 302
```

Comment: for the task:

 - name: dates
      debug: msg="{{(ansible_winrm_certificate_expires - ansible_date_time.iso8601).days}}"

I get:

{"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ansible_winrm_certificate_expires - ansible_date_time.date}}): unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'"}

Comment: if your variables are strings, you are out of luck here... i guess a custom filter is your only way here.

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:
        - name: someday
          prompt: insert some day with format yyyy-mm-dd
          private: false



  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (now()  - ( someday | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days  }}"
```