# Ansible: compare difference between two dates for the last hour

Tags: date, amazon-ec2, time, ansible, jinja2

there is a way to compare between the *current time* using `ansible_date_time`
with another date (aws ec2 launch time) So I will be able to know if it happened in the last hour?

I have the following var `ec2_launch_time: 2018-01-04T15:57:52+00:00`

I know that I can compare **days** with the following method (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760587/how-to-check-if-the-difference-between-2-dates-is-or-1-month-in-jinja2-templ) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029448/ansible-date-compare-ec2?rq=1)):

```
"{{ (ansible_date_time.iso8601[:19] | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') - ec2_launch_time[:19] | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')).days }}"
```

if I will get **0** I will know that it happened on the same day but I'm looking for a way to get true or false if the difference between the dates are **1 hour (on the same day)**.

there is a filter for this or elegant way to write this or only using shell (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116503/how-to-compare-two-datetime-strings-and-return-difference-in-hours-bash-shell))?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By subtracting two dates, you get a [`timedelta` Python object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

You can use [`total_seconds` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to get the exact difference in seconds. Add some basic arithmetic to get the number of full hours:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    date_later: 2018-01-05 08:30:00
    date_earlier: 2018-01-05 06:50:00
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ( (date_later - date_earlier).total_seconds() / 3600 ) | int }}"
```

returns:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1"
}
```

Use the above expression in the condition you want.

Comment: thanks @techraf, this worked for me `(ansible_date_time.iso8601[:19] | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') - ec2_launch_time[:19] | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')).total_seconds() / 3600 | int <= 1 `