# Date time difference using Ansible

Tags: ansible

How to calculate the difference in seconds between below two date variables using Ansible.

date1: 06/01/2021 00:10:15.434
date2: 06/01/2021 00:10:26.667

Tried to_datetime gives does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' error.
If the dates are in yyyy-mm-dd format the difference calculation works, but not getting with above date format.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101921/ansible-compare-difference-between-two-dates-for-the-last-hour

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 06/01/2021 is in the month, date, year format, use this code.

```
((date2 | to_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')) - (date1 | to_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Tried this various ways, gives an templating error and format issues.

Comment: Am getting these date vars from a long string, not ansible_date_time fact

Comment: had used the same, gives 'datetime.datetime object' has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: datetime.datetime.total_seconds is new in Python 3.2. Which version of Python is Ansible using?

Comment: Yes, it's older one. I'll try in our latest env and update here.